# Is there a way to tell if an archive mirror is up to date?

Tags: debian, archiving, mirroring

As of late, I've been noticing that the usual mirror I select during installation has been annoyingly slow, so I decided to go ahead and find a new one and test that.

I read around on the Internet a bit, and came across a thread on a website that said that Synaptic Package Manager can find the best one for you in your region; I gave that a shot, and it did select one indeed, and it wasn't the one I was using.

Specifically, it was http://debian.mirror.constant.com/.

I looked at the website itself and the files it contains - Debian "Jessie"'s archives were updated today, if I'm reading it correctly, but I'm using 7.3, "Wheezy" which hasn't been updated since December 14th.

http://debian.mirror.constant.com/dists/stable/main/

Is this the correct place to be looking? December 14th was some time ago, but I know software releases take some time to be officially released to distributions.

My question to you all, as the title says: Is there a way to tell if an archive mirror is up to date?

(Small update: I can't seem to select the tags I want, as they're changed automatically. I typed in "archive" and "mirror" but they're not allowed. Can someone suggest other tags I may use to get my point across?)

Answer (score 0):

Debian 7.3 has been released on December the 14th, so there nothing wrong there. You can always look at the [debian site](https://www.debian.org/News/) for news

You might be interested in adding the [update directory](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates) that contain update of thing like virus definition that has to be updated more often than Debian is.

You also have the [proposed-update](https://wiki.debian.org/StableProposedUpdates) and [backport](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) archive, but update available in proposed-update are not always well tested (your are welcome to test, but don't use on production server). Backport is using some more recent version of software backported from testing to stable (like the last version of libreoffice). Again it will be less tested than stable, and probably not meant for server.

Comment: Well, I mean, like, what archive does software like Pidgin and XChat come from? I just want to make sure that software like such are up to date like the ftp.us.debian.org archive is. Will the debian.mirror.constant.com archive be up to date like the one directly from Debian is? Just want to make sure it is before I use it in a new install. It's not a production server, so.

Comment: I answered your question in a separate answer. But if you are nervouse about one mirror why use it? Just use ftp.us

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Remi provided you with the information you wanted. However to answer how to check if a mirror is valid check the mirrors status page:

http://mirror.debian.org/status.html

Comment: If they did, I don't quite understand it then. I understand that Debian 7.3 was released on December 14th, but does that also mean all packages downloaded from the apt repositories (mirror) don't get updated for it anymore and you must wait until testing becomes stable? (In a general sense, I know you can add other repos to your sources.list) - Also, I'm not questioning the validity of the mirror, just if the packages it contains are up to date. For example, ftp.us.debian.org contains Pidgin 2.10.6 - debian.mirror.constant.com may contain Pidgin 2.10.5 - that's all I mean by "up to date."

Comment: Whether the mirror's packages are the same as the primary mirrors, updates and all. (Sorry for the double comment, character limits.)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a archive mirror is up to date: 
https://mirror-master.debian.org/status/mirror-status.html

You can try [**netselect-apt**](https://packages.debian.org/buster/netselect-apt) tool. Using netselect command it will test the full Debian mirror list in order to find the fastest/closest one and generate a new source.list with the chosen mirror.

You execute:

```
foo@bar:/home/foo# netselect-apt wheezy
```

The output will look like these:

```
The fastest 10 servers seem to be:

http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/debian/
http://ftp.cl.debian.org/debian/
http://debian.utalca.cl/debian/
http://debian.repo.cure.edu.uy/debian/
http://debian.netlinux.cl/debian/
http://mirror.unesp.br/debian/
http://debian.pop-sc.rnp.br/debian/

Of the hosts tested we choose the fastest valid for HTTP:
    http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/debian/
```